# Display Arraylist Items as Separate JLabels

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, dictionary, jlabel

I'm making an ordering system application. I want the user to click a button, add the item of the button they clicked to an `arraylist`, and display the `arraylist` at the bottom of the screen.

I currently can add the item to the list, but having trouble displaying each item as it's own `JLabel`. So, how do I do it, or how is it properly done.

Shortened examples.

**MenuPanel.Java**

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

        OrderPanel.getOrder().add("bread");

        meatMenu(); //Changes panel display (not important)

        System.out.println(OrderPanel.getOrder());

    }
});
```

**OrderPanel.Java**

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

order = new ArrayList<String>();

map.put("order", order);

System.out.println(order);

l1 = new JLabel();
    l1.setFont(l1.getFont().deriveFont(FONT_POINTS));
    l1.add(order.toString()); //Error on add
    add(l1);
```

I can `System.out.print` the items in the list with no problem, but cannot display them in a JLabel. :/

**EDIT: NullPointerException Issue**

```
public JLabel holder;

public static List<String> order;

order = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++) {
    holder = new JLabel();
    holder.setText(order.get(i).toString());
    labels.add(holder);
}

System.out.print(holder); // Works
add(holder); // Doesn't work - throws exception
```

Comment: If you want each item on the ArrayList to be its own button, you want to make a for each loop, probably using an array of JLabels

Comment: I want each item in the list to be it's own `jlabel`. How would I implement a for loop to do this?

Comment: see answer below. It is just an example, not necessarily the best thing to do

Answer (score 3):

A for loop to put each item in the array list into its own JLabel would look something like:

```
 ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>(); //not 100% sure on this syntax off the top of my head

 JLabel holder;

 for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++){
        holder = new JLabel();
        holder.setText(order.get(i))  // assuming order's objects are Strings, otherwise .toString() on there somewhere
        labels.add(holder); //adds holder to the ArrayList of JLabels
 }
```

this gives you an ArrayList of JLabels, one with each item from your order ArrayList.  There are probably better ways to integrate this into your code, but this is an example (for example, integrating it where you populate your orders ArrayList to populate them as JLabels instead, but YMMV).

**NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**
You are getting a Null Pointer exception because you are not using the add syntax correctly.  It should be:

instanceOfArrayList.add(Object)

Comment: You can use for-each, too. for(String s : order){... }

Comment: @pL4Gu33 right, but I couldn't recall the syntax for that off the top of my head

Comment: I understand this example and it seems to be working, but now I can't `add(holder)` to my code. It keeps throwing a nullpointerexception, yet `System.out.print(holder)` works perfectly. Any ideas? Thank you by the way!

Comment: in the example above, holder should always have an address except right before the for loop.  Can you update with your new code and I can try to figure it out.

Comment: @MikeMilla see my added explanation